# How to print and sum specific data from logfiles

Tags: python, logging, printing, sum, extract

I need a Python script to analyze the contents of a log file. The log files (named like: `log.txt.2014-01-01`) are made up as follows:

```
....<different structure>

2013-05-09 19:09:20,112 [1] DEBUG Management.Handle - Action: Amount=005,00; Date=25.04.2013 19:25:04

2013-05-09 19:09:20,112 [1] DEBUG Management.Handle - Action: Amount=005,00; Date=25.04.2013 19:27:05

2013-05-09 19:09:20,112 [1] DEBUG Management.Handle - Action: Amount=005,00; Date=25.04.2013 19:28:05

...<different structure>
```

I need to sum the `Amount` and print the total.

Comment: So by *"help me finalizing"* you mean *"write"*?

Comment: how can you add `005,00`

Comment: @vks I think that's 005.00 in a European locale, like the milliseconds part of the time stamp.

Comment: It's a value (euro €)

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
from cStringIO import StringIO

def extractAmount(file_like):
    amountRe = re.compile('^.* Management\.Handle - Action: Amount=(\d+),(\d+);')
    for line in file_like:
        result = amountRe.match(line)
        if result:
            matches = result.groups()
            yield (float(matches[0]) + (float(matches[1]) / 100.0))

data = StringIO("""....<different structure>
2013-05-09 19:09:20,112 [1] DEBUG Management.Handle - Action: Amount=005,00; Date=25.04.2013 19:25:04
2013-05-09 19:09:20,112 [1] DEBUG Management.Handle - Action: Amount=005,00; Date=25.04.2013 19:27:05
2013-05-09 19:09:20,112 [1] DEBUG Management.Handle - Action: Amount=005,00; Date=25.04.2013 19:28:05
...<different structure>""")

print sum(extractAmount(data))
```

In the example I've used a [cStringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) object to load the data, but this approach should work with any iterable that gives strings (such as the file object from `open`).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x=<your_test_string>
z= [float(re.sub(r",",".",i)) for i in re.findall(r"(?<=DEBUG Management\.Handle - Action: Amount=)([^;]+)",x)]
print sum(z)
```

You can try this.

Try

http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import+re%0Ax%3D%22%22%22....%3Cdifferent+structure%3E%0A%0A2013-05-09+19%3A09%3A20,112+%5B1%5D+DEBUG+Management.Handle+-+Action%3A+Amount%3D005,00%3B+Date%3D25.04.2013+19%3A25%3A04%0A%0A2013-05-09+19%3A09%3A20,112+%5B1%5D+DEBUG+Management.Handle+-+Action%3A+Amount%3D005,00%3B+Date%3D25.04.2013+19%3A27%3A05%0A%0A2013-05-09+19%3A09%3A20,112+%5B1%5D+DEBUG+Management.Handle+-+Action%3A+Amount%3D005,00%3B+Date%3D25.04.2013+19%3A28%3A05%0A%0A...%3Cdifferent+structure%3E%22%22%22%0Az%3D+%5Bfloat(re.sub(r%22,%22,%22.%22,i))+for+i+in+re.findall(r%22(%3F%3C%3DDEBUG+Management%5C.Handle+-+Action%3A+Amount%3D)(%5B%5E%3B%5D%2B)%22,x)%5D%0Aprint+sum(z)&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=7

Comment: When I try your code (vks) I receive the error message:     print "Total: " + sum(z)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: @Vroluk try `print "Total:"+str(sum(z))`

Comment: Though, if the log files are of any appreciable size, storing the whole file in memory and then building the complete list of floats will be slower than a generator based approach.

Comment: The log files are quite small (+/- 300 lines).@vks: No more error message but the result is "0"?